# Project not found ao tentar instalar o Entity pelo NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, instalador, nuget

A lista suspensa onde estão ou deveriam estar listados todos os projetos de minha solution, está vindo em branco. O que eu devo fazer para listar os projetos lá? Já dei um rebuild e mesmo assim continua vazia. A lista é a `Default Project` do `Package Manage Console`

Comment: Pode parecer brincadeira, mas já tentou reiniciar o VS?

Comment: @Randrade, vou fazer essa "brincadeira", eheheh

Comment: @Randrade, a brincadeira deu certo, eheheh. Obrigado, mas não entendi porque não estava funcionando e eu havia dado um clean na solution.

Comment: O VS as vezes da isso. Sempre que achar que algo estranho está acontecendo, faça a "Solução Windows" e reinicie o VS.

Comment: Algumas vezes é necessário reiniciar a máquina também.